# Payment gateway API that allows transferring money to credit card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, credit-card

I'm looking for a way to accept money from credit cards and send money from my account to someone's credit card. Does anyone know of an API/Gateway that allows me to do this?

I'm working in Rails.

Thanks to all helpers!

Uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I assume you're integrated into an online payment gateway such as Cybersource, Stripe, Braintree or anything else. You'd need that to process cards and each has its own integration documentation and gems.
Once integrated, you want to issue a REFUND to a credit card. This will send money to that card, debiting your bank account. Now the tricky part is that most processors demand a preliminary positive transaction to make a refund, which isn't your case. You're looking for something called `stand alone credit` or `stand alone refund`, which some processors require special permission for.
I've used this with Cybersource via Paymentech in the past. Have a look at [page 45 in their documentation](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/CC_Svcs_SCMP_API/Credit_Cards_SCMP_API.pdf).
Alternatively, the easiest way to pay someone to his credit card is via a wallet. PayPal is the most popular wallet so you can use that, allowing users to draw their funds into a credit card.
If your comapny is big enough, it can also use Payout services such as Tipalti and Payoneer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll look into these options

Answer (score 0):

The standard gem for this is [active_merchant](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant).

You can transfer money to other accounts, if the gateway supports this.
See [API documentation of transfer](http://rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/master/ActiveMerchant/Billing/PaypalCommonAPI%3atransfer)

Comment: But does active merchant have anyway to transfer funds to a selected credit card?